# Copy file extension without preserving the folder structure

Tags: linux, unix

I have a set of file list located at different folder and I would like to copy it to a different location after filtering the files without preserving the folder structure .

`find -regex '.*\(xml\|hex\|out\)' | cpio -pdm /data/Folder/Project/GUI/output`

After I execute the command above it the folder structure are copied to output folder as well which is not the result that I want instead I want the output files to be inside the output folder only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer but can someone explain why I need to use -exec for the cp ?Whats the "{}" for ? and why at the end of the command I had to add a \ and also a ;

`find -regex '.*\(xml\|hex\|out\|rc\|map\)' -exec cp {} /data/Folder/Project/GUI/output/ \;`